# How sort by Ascending Order using datagrid view column values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my datagridview having column name like 
SNo,Customer Name,Salary,Range

I need to sort ascending order "Customer Name" how its possible?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Sort` method of `datagridview` like

1) You can provide a column name

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["CustomerName"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

OR

2) You may also use index of column like

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: @kadhir, view the answer might be help you :)

Comment: ,which event  have to write this Code??

Comment: better to write after your database call